# Android Studio ——How can I modify one Class's field before compile by build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, task, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my Android App that I'm developing with Android Studio, I have a class:

```
public class Config
{
  public static final String SDK_VERSION = "0.1";
}
```

I want to modify the value of the `SDK_VERSION` field by changing the file `build.gradle`:

```
def SDK_VERSION = "0.1"

android
{
  defaultConfig {
      versionName SDK_VERSION
  }
}
```

How can I make the value of `SDK_VERSION` in `Config.java` change automatically when I change it in `build.gradle`? Otherwise, I might change one but forget to change the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for example in the your starter Activity in onCreate(), but make in not final befor.

```
Config.sdk_version = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

Or why don't just use BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME; instead in the place where this constant is needed?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know the BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME before.How long do you learn Android, and How do you learn Android?

Comment: 1.5 year; on the Coursera